# HTML Tables, Table Headers

Tags: html, html-table

I have an array of size n. Each element of the array is a table header:

```
<th> "array[0]" </th>

<th> "array[1]" </th>

...

<th> "array[n]" </th>
```

How can I automatically create n table headers without LITERALLY writing all that? Like a loop that goes over the array and create a table header with each element of the array.

Comment: What you have tried? this can be achieved by simple looping and if checks, and in any language @j08691

Comment: HTML or PHP (I'm using both in my program)

Comment: This site should be a good place for you to start: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forloop.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP as your comment indicated, you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $header) {
    echo "<th>$header</th>";  
}
```

See this site for a more complex tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forloop.php

and here for more on `foreach`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php